# Select rows that contains unique value ( non-redundant)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given this table:

| id | Name | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | B1 | 2022-02-26 |
| 21 | B | 2022-02-26 |
| 01 | C1 | 2022-02-26 |
| 04 | T1 | 2022-02-16 |
| 04 | T | 2022-02-16 |

PS: This table is the result of join request.

I want to select the rows with corrurent day where Id doesn't repeated like:

| id | Name | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | C1 | 2022-02-26 |

How I can do that with SQL query please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DB**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  name CHAR,
  date DATE
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'A', '2022-02-22');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'B', '2022-02-21');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 'C', '2022-02-20');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 'D', '2022-02-19');
```

**QUERY**

```
select * from test
where id in (select id from test group by id having count(*) = 1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id  name date
2   C    2022-02-20
3   D    2022-02-19
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pPLkZQpGZ2AfwZe23h1zPH/1)

Comment: I have an important rows in my table ( large numbers of records) the query work but is not the expected result

Comment: @DYAMB It should also work

Comment: i have also date column in my table and the Query show just the to last date !

Comment: @DYAMB modify your question by adding extra column that also need to be concerned. Then give another expected result.

Comment: Modification done

Comment: @DYAMB I update my answer. It still works like a charm.

Comment: The same result for me .Thanks for you sir, the query correctly makes sense. I'll see the pb from me .

Comment: Please if i wanna add condition for extract just rows non redundant in the current date ?

Comment: @DYAMB modify your question by adding extra condition that also need to be concerned. Then give another expected result.

Comment: @ YuTing Please i edited the result.

Comment: @DYAMB My query function still works like a charm in  your new condition. What do you actually need ?

Comment: PS: This table is the result of join request, mean i joinded two tables to get this table, then from this table i'll get the result expected as it shown in my question.

Comment: @DYAMB accept this answer would be great

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as 
(
    select id, count(Name) as cnt
    from TableName
    group by id
)
select cte.id, tableName.Name
from cte 
inner join TableName on
cte.id = tableName.id
where cte.cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,name from test
where ID NOT IN ( select id from test group by id having count(*)> 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from test where id not in
(select distinct id from 
(select *,row_number () 
 over (partition by id order by Name asc) rn 
from test
) b
where rn>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table name is `Test`. The below query would work.

```
Select *
From Test
Group by Id
Having count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do this is likely to be using window functions to check if there is another row

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      LEAD(id) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Name) rn 
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE t.nxt IS NULL;
```